# JavaScript Array Sort Order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Using JavaScript (no jQuery) - I am attempting to display a list of 9 items based on a sortOrder attribute.  The issue is that not all 9 items will be in the array. I need to detect a missing sortOrder from the array and display an empty div in its place but am not sure where to begin.

Below is the data (notice that data for sortOrder '5' is missing):

```
"items":[  
  {  
     "name":"Lorem Ipsum",
     "sortOrder":1,
  },
  {  
     "name":"Dolor Sit",
     "sortOrder":2,
  },
  {  
     "name":"Amet Consectur",
     "sortOrder":3,
  },
  {  
     "name":"Adipising Elit",
     "sortOrder":4,
  },
  {  
    "name":"Lorem Dolor",
    "sortOrder":6,
  },
  {  
     "name":"Sit Amet",
     "sortOrder":7,
  },
  {  
     "name":"Elit Adipising",
     "sortOrder":8,
  },
  {  
     "name":"Dorem Consectur",
     "sortOrder":9,
  }
]
```

I would like for the output to be as follows:

- Lorem Ipsum
- Dolor Sit
- Amet Consectur
- Adipising Elit
- **[EMPTY DIV]**
- Lorem Dolor
- Sit Amet
- Elit Adipising
- Dorem Consectur

However, I am getting this instead:

- Lorem Ipsum
- Dolor Sit
- Amet Consectur
- Adipising Elit
- Lorem Dolor
- Sit Amet
- Elit Adipising
- Dorem Consectur
- **[EMPTY DIV]**

Comment: you can not sort something and include some missing at the same time. maybe you include the output part as well.

Comment: Why don't you post your code too?

Comment: When building the output, check if the `currentSortOrder - previousSortOrder > 1` and if so add that number of empty divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you, essentially you append the Array with Object References & then fill the missing with whatever.

```js
var data ={ "items":
           [  
    {  
       "name":"Lorem Ipsum",
       "sortOrder":1,
    },
    {  
       "name":"Dolor Sit",
       "sortOrder":2,
    },
    {  
       "name":"Amet Consectur",
       "sortOrder":3,
    },
    {  
       "name":"Adipising Elit",
       "sortOrder":4,
    },
    {  
      "name":"Lorem Dolor",
      "sortOrder":6,
    },
    {  
       "name":"Sit Amet",
       "sortOrder":7,
    },
    {  
       "name":"Elit Adipising",
       "sortOrder":8,
    },
    {  
       "name":"Dorem Consectur",
       "sortOrder":9,
    }
  ]
}

data.items.forEach((item,i,array) => { data.items['item:'+item.sortOrder] = item; });

var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
      .map(sortOrder => { return (data.items['item:'+sortOrder] || { name: 'Missing', sortOrder: sortOrder }); });
      
console.log(JSON.stringify(list,null,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option how to do this (if you have small arrays):

```
 var renderArr = function(arr, render) {
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math,arr.map(function(o){return o.sortOrder;}));

  for(var i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    var el = arr.find(function(e) {     
        return e.sortOrder === i;
    });

    if(el) {
        render(el.name);
    }
    else {
        render("[EMPTY DIV]");
    }
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

renderArr(items, function(content) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = content;  
    document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].appendChild(li);
});
```

Here is an example of usage:
https://jsfiddle.net/qyyq959c/